# Как создать кликабельные ссылки на имя в массиве в javascript , чтобы выводило комментарии каждого имени

Tags: javascript, html, массивы

Как сделать так, чтобы при нажатии на каждое имя выводились комментарии этого имени?

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <title>Document</title>
</head>

<body>

</body>
<script type="text/javascript">
  var coms = [{
      Name: 'Jack',
      text: 'Love JS'
    },
    {
      Name: 'Brad',
      text: 'Ok lets start'
    },
    {
      Name: 'Lily',
      text: 'Playing football'
    },
    {
      Name: 'Boris',
      text: 'Interesting'
    },
    {
      Name: 'Lily',
      text: '0 problems'
    },
  ];

  let tmp = new Set(coms);
  tmp.forEach((value, key, arr) => {
    for (let prop in value) document.write(`${value[prop ]}  <br>`)
  });
  document.write("<br><b>All Comments</b><br>");

  let map = new Map();
  coms.reduce((map, com) => {
    if (map.has(com.Name)) {
      map.set(com.Name, map.get(com.Name) + ", " + com.text);
      return map;
    }
    return map.set(com.Name, com.text);
  }, map);
  map.forEach((value, key, map) => document.write(`${key}: ${value}<br>`));
</script>

</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

Если используете современный синтаксис JS, то не нужно усложнять:

```js
const USERS = document.querySelector('.users');
const COMMS = document.querySelector('.comments');

let coms = [
  { Name: 'Jack',  text: 'Love JS' },
  { Name: 'Brad',  text: 'Ok lets start' },
  { Name: 'Lily',  text: 'Playing football' },
  { Name: 'Boris', text: 'Interesting' },
  { Name: 'Lily',  text: '0 problems' }
];
let aNames = [...new Set(coms.map((el) => el.Name))];

aNames.forEach((el) => {
  USERS.insertAdjacentHTML('beforeend', `<a href="${el}" onclick="fShowComm(event)">${el}</a>`);
});

function fShowComm(ev) {
  ev.preventDefault();
  let sComms = coms.filter((el) => el.Name === ev.target.textContent).map((el) => `<p>${el.text}</p>`).join('');
  COMMS.innerHTML = `<p>${ev.target.textContent} said:</p>${sComms}`;
}
```

```css
/* Only for example --> */ .users{margin:10px auto;display:flex;justify-content:space-between;align-items:center;gap:.25em;width:min-content}.users>a{padding:.5em 1em;border-radius:.25em;text-decoration:none;color:#fff;box-shadow:inset 5px 5px 10px #fff8,inset -5px -5px 10px #0008,inset 0 0 0 2em #888}.comments{margin:10px auto;display:flex;flex-direction:column;justify-content:flex-start;align-items:flex-start;width:max-content}.comments>p{margin:0;padding:.5em 1em;border-radius:5px;box-shadow:inset 1px 2px 10px -6px #0008}.comments>p:first-child{padding:.5em 0;box-shadow:none}
```

```html
<div class="users"></div><div class="comments"></div>
```

Лучше "добить" оформлением жажду кодинга ;-)